# TypeError: No matching overloads found for java.util.Properties.setProperty(str,str)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-athena, pyathena

I was trying to connect to an athena database with PyAthenaJDBC. I was looking for some information about how to do this and I trid this code:

```
import contextlib
from urllib.parse import quote_plus  # PY2: from urllib import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import select
from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import func
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Table, MetaData

conn_str = 'awsathena+jdbc://{access_key}:{secret_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com:443/'\
           '{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}'
engine = create_engine(conn_str.format(
    access_key=quote_plus('YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'),
    secret_key=quote_plus('YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
    region_name='us-west-2',
    schema_name='default',
    s3_staging_dir=quote_plus('s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/')))
try:
    with contextlib.closing(engine.connect()) as conn:
        many_rows = Table('many_rows', MetaData(bind=engine), autoload=True)
        print(select([func.count('*')], from_obj=many_rows).scalar())
finally:
    engine.dispose()
```

but when I run this code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: No matching overloads found for java.util.Properties.setProperty(str,str), options are:
    public synchronized java.lang.Object java.util.Properties.setProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

    at JPMethod::findOverload(native\common\jp_method.cpp:242)
    at JPMethod::findOverload(native\common\jp_method.cpp:245)
    at JPMethod::invoke(native\common\jp_method.cpp:253)
    at PyJPMethod::__call__(native\python\pyjp_method.cpp:167)
```

Can someone please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see any PyAthenaJDBC library imported in your code. Can you run something basic from here  https://pypi.org/project/PyAthenaJDBC/1.0.7/ and let me know if you are able to ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was connecting using integer values for various connection properties. Once I converted all my connection values to strings, the driver went on to connect just fine.

For your config - it may be the `autoload=True` parameter, which you might try replacing with `autoload="True"`

In other words, setProperty only ever expects a pair of string parameters, and gets confused when you pass in content that's in non-string values.